# How can I add Variables to this Node JS Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, telegram

I am creating a Movie Search Bot using NodeJS and MongoDB. I use Following Code to Search movies.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {

  const uri = "mongodb+srv://******************";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const mydb = client.db("Cluster0").collection("-100****");

  try {
    await client.connect();

    await myFunc(mydb, "inputW1", "inputW2");

  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function myFunc(mydb, word1, word2) {

  const projection = { _id: 0, file_name: 1, file_size: 1, link: 1 };
  const query = { 
    $text: { 
      $search: "\"avengers\" \"2012\"" 
    }
  }
  const cursor = await mydb.find(query).project(projection);
}
```

Above code gives Perfect Search Result for me.
But I don't know how to insert that **word1** & **word2** Parameters into the Function as Vars. If I replace *avengers* and *2012* words with parameters it read as constant.
How can I insert them to function as Variables...

Comment: Don't see issue related to python, hence removing python tag.

Comment: This also does not seem to be a question about C++.

Comment: Please don't spam tags on your post. This is not related to `c++` nor `python`, and I'm not sure this is related to `telegram` either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$search: `"${word1}" "${word2}"`
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
const query = {
    $text: {
        $search: `\"${word1}\" \"${word2}\"`
    }
}
```